# How to apply javascript function for different divs with sames classname?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written the javascript, which shows only 3 chars of the text, if the text-content has more than 3 chars.

```
//var msg = $('.message-content').children('p');
var msg = $('.message-content').text();

if(msg.length >3){
    $(".message-content").html(msg.substring(0,3));
    $( ".more-hidden" ).html( msg.substring(3)).hide();
    $(".readmore").css("visibility", 'visible');
    $(".message-content").css("float", 'left');
}

 $('.readmore').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.more-hidden').slideToggle();
    $(this).text( $(this).text() == '... Read More' ? "Show Less" : "... Read More");
});
```

When clicked on the "show more" link, the whole text is displayed. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/71w7tagr/19/). This works fine.

Now the problem is that the user adds `<div class="message-content">some commit </div>` dynamically. My question is: How to apply the same function for all `<div class="message-content">some commit </div>`?

Comment: You will need to call your trim-function everytime a new div has been inserted. Another (not recommented) approach is calling your trim-function every x seconds.

Comment: Use delegated events or use a mutation observer and add the event directly when the element is appended to the DOM.

Comment: I believe you are looking for a delegated event.  Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/on/ updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/71w7tagr/20/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want?

```js
$('.message-content').each(function () {
    var toggle = $('<a href="#">... Read More</a>')
        .addClass('readmore')
        .insertAfter($(this));
    var more = $('<div></div>')
        .addClass('more-hidden')
        .insertAfter($(this));

    var msg = $(this).text();
    if (msg.length > 3) {
        $(this).html(msg.substring(0, 3));

        more.html(msg.substring(3)).hide();
        toggle.css("visibility", 'visible');
        $(this).css("float", 'left');
    }

    toggle.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        more.slideToggle();
        $(this).text($(this).text() == '... Read More' ? "Show Less" : "... Read More");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message-content">1)nice product</div><br/>
<div class="message-content">2)nice product</div><br/>
<div class="message-content">3)nice product</div><br/>
<div class="message-content">4)nice product</div><br/>
```

With this code you can add any number of `.message-content` elements and that codes automatically add `.more-hidden` and `.readmore` elements

Comment: Hi abforce, this sound to be exact what I am looking for :). I will test it now

Comment: Is there any possibility to insert the .more-hidden and the href ONLY IF the text.length>x? more-hidden div and the href makes redundant distance see here http://jsfiddle.net/71w7tagr/36/

Comment: @Max_Salah yeah, It's possible! see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/71w7tagr/37/) put all these stuff into a `if`

Answer (score 1):

You need to run that batch of codes again to apply it to new elements. One simple thing you could do is to write it as a function and call that function when you insert a new div. Something like:

```
function Shortify() {
  $('.message-content').text(function(i, text) {
    if (text.length > 3) {
      $(this).html(text.substring(0, 3));

      $(this).siblings(".more-hidden").html(text.substring(3)).hide();
      $(this).siblings(".readmore").css("visibility", 'visible');
      $(this).css("float", 'left');
    }
  });
}
```

Another solution would be to listen for when an element with `message-content`class added into the DOM and manipulate it to match your need. You can use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for this. But be warned this more complex and you will need to tweak things if you want consistent behaviour through different browsers.

Comment: That is because i had forgotten to replace your `msg` variables with `text` variable as i should. See http://jsfiddle.net/71w7tagr/30/.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function `.on` function for your link. So you can append only one handler for all your divs, but you still have to call your `trim` every time when user added/updated comment.

Example of using jQuery `.on` function:

```
// container - it is your comments parent block
var $container = $('.container');
$container.on('click', '.readmore', function(e) {
    // your handler
});
```

You can see work example here: http://jsfiddle.net/uk1qbd7s/1/